# Geocaching websites

Tags: geocaching

I'm new to [Geocaching](https://www.geocaching.com/) and I was wondering what else I've been missing out on. I didn't know where to ask this but if you know and love any similar adventure / exploring services please share!

Comment: This question is pretty broad, and doesn't really fit the Stack Exchange format. Take a look at [ask] and consider [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Geocaching covers a lot nowadays, but there is also [letterboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_%28hobby%29) which is similar... bit of a broad question as nhinkle said.

Comment: I'd have to agree with nhinkle and Aravona here - list questions don't fit on Stack Exchange, so I'll close. I'd suggest looking at Ingress, though - millions of people love the exploring/competitive nature of it (including me)

Answer (score 1):

A derivate of Geocashing is [Geohashing](http://wiki.xkcd.com/geohashing/), which started with an xkcd comic. The basic principle is the same: you take a pair of coordinates and try to get there.
What differs is the way these coordinates are generated. As the page linked above describes, they are generated randomly each day for each 1°×1° latitude/longitude zone. A good place to look today's location for your area is [geohashing.info](http://geohashing.info/).

You won't find any treasures at the end (usually...), but it's a fun way to explore the countryside around you. You might go somewhere and discover places you'd never go to otherwise.